# Why Protege add the `xml` namespace to my ontology?

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, protege

I'm using Protégé to edit my ontology, but everytime it adds xml namespace to it.

> xml http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace

I don't know why, and I didn't use it anywhere in my ontology.

[image]

And the delete option is always disabled for `xml`.

Comment: It's just a prefix. It can't be harmful. In this case, it's useless, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: but when I save, it also adds it to my ontology file, which I don't want...

Comment: Then delete it from your file. You could also leave it. As far as performance is concerned, an unused prefix has virtually no incidence. What is the reason you would like it to disappear from your file?

Comment: When I use Widoco to generate the documentation, it will think "used namespace xml" when I didn't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML prefix is part of the prefixes that are always written out - owl, rdf, rdfs, xsd, xml. There is no logical implication, these are plain shortcuts used in the XML layer; if unused, their effect is nil. If used, they reduce the size of the output file.